# Java Slick Collision Detection Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, static, nullpointerexception, collision-detection, slick

I'm attempting to make a basic top down shooter and I am having a little trouble with my Enemy spawning. I have managed to get the spawning to work correctly but when attempting to add a collision rectangle, upon initialising it, it wants to become static, which if I make it static, then it wants the X and Y to become static, which isn't an option.

I have a player class which represents the playable character and the rectangle works fine in that class, so I assume it is to do with the class instances.

```
package com.space.shooter;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle;

public class Enemy extends Entity{
int carPosX;
float carPosY;
static Rectangle enemyCollisionBox;
static Image car;

Enemy(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
    carPosX = x;
    carPosY = y;
}

static void init () throws SlickException{
    car = new Image ("src/data/Car.png");
    enemyCollisionBox = new Rectangle(carPosX, -36, car.getWidth(), car.getHeight());
}

boolean isDestroyed(){
    if (carPosY > Engine.height){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static void spawn(int x) throws SlickException{

    switch (x){

    case (0):
        x = Engine.width/2-40;
        break;
    case (1):
        x = Engine.width/2-10;
        break;
    case (2):
        x = Engine.width/2+20;
        break;
    }

    Play.enemies.add(new Enemy(x, -36));
    //System.out.println(Play.enemies.size());
    init();
}

void update (GameContainer gc){
    Input input = gc.getInput();

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE)){
        carPosY += 6 + (1 * Play.level);
    } else {
        carPosY += 0.95 + (1 * Play.level); // was 0.95;
    }
}

void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(car, carPosX, carPosY);
}
}
```

Please don't judge my code too harshly, this is my first time attempting a full blown game plus I have been adding code out of desperation and it gets a bit messy. I had to do some last minute touches to the code whilst in this post so it may be a little incorrect.

I can't figure out what the solution to the rectangle problem is.

Thanks

Comment: What does "it wants to be static" mean? Where do you get the NPE? Do you have a stack trace to share?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explanation. When I said it wanted to be static, I meant my IDE (Eclipse) highlights the syntax and suggests it to be made static. And forgive me for being un-knowledgable but is the stack trace the list of errors which specify a line number. I'm going to try a full rewrite of the class to see if that helps.

Comment: If you still have problems after the rewrite, please the question with the new code and the output of the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the contents of your init method to work like this;

```
package com.space.shooter;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle;

public class Enemy extends Entity{
    int carPosX;
    float carPosY;
    Rectangle enemyCollisionBox;
    static Image car=null;

    Enemy(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        carPosX = x;
        carPosY = y;
        enemyCollisionBox = new Rectangle(carPosX, -36, car.getWidth(), car.getHeight());
    }

    static void init () throws SlickException{
        if(car==null)car = new Image ("src/data/Car.png");
    }

    boolean isDestroyed(){
        if (carPosY > Engine.height){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static void spawn(int x) throws SlickException{

        switch (x){

        case (0):
            x = Engine.width/2-40;
            break;
        case (1):
            x = Engine.width/2-10;
            break;
        case (2):
            x = Engine.width/2+20;
            break;
        }

        init();
        Play.enemies.add(new Enemy(x, -36));
        //System.out.println(Play.enemies.size());
    }

    void update (GameContainer gc){
        Input input = gc.getInput();

        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE)){
            carPosY += 6 + (1 * Play.level);
        } else {
            carPosY += 0.95 + (1 * Play.level); // was 0.95;
        }
    }

    void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(car, carPosX, carPosY);
    }
}
```

That would solve your problem about collision box needing to be `static`, however you haven't provided any detail regarding your `NullPointerException`. I also added a check to prevent you reloading the car `Image` every time you create a new enemy. If you have many resources you should preload them before the game starts.

---

To better explain how the `static` keyword works;

`static` methods and variables belong the `class` rather than an instance of the `class` (an `object`). This means that `static` methods/vars can be accessed from anywhere that required access (`private`/`public`/`protected`). As a `static` method is not connected to an object, it is unable to access instance (non-static) variables unless you pass it an `Object` and it access them through that `Object`.

Comment: That kind of works. It does eliminate the need for my collision rectangle to be static. But now when I run, I still get a NPE where it would spawn an enemy. I think it has something to do with the carPosX, I'm going to attempt a rewrite of the class now I know how to stop the collision being static. Thanks again.

Comment: Which line are you referring to by 'where it would spawn an enemy' ? If it is `Play.enemies.add(new Enemy(x, -36));` then `Play.enemies` must be null.